# Track user actions in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I'm having requirement to track each action an user performs in Alfresco.

I want to write a Spring interceptor which is having advice "**Around**" and when user performs any of the action after login to portal, that should be tracked.

Action that user performs, parameters for that action should be available to custom interceptor.

Please help me if any one knows how to implement this kind of scenario.

Comment: What kinds of actions are you interested in? At the web request level? Service level? Other?

Comment: all kind of requests, let say if user is navigating from one place to another place, creating an event in calendar, creating a content.

Comment: Web Request level then? Or service level? i.e. a call to `/api/foo/bar/create` or a call to `FooService.create(thing)` ? They're likely to be rather different in how you wrap them

Comment: Could you not use the audit functionality already present in Alfresco? https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Content_Auditing

Answer (score 1):

It is probably quite late, but still :)

Audit is supported out of the box. But as I understood it is turned on by default only for records management. For share actions you need to do several sreps:

1. Create file `extenstion/audit/alfresco-audit-node.xml`
2. Register an application for the actions upon node, for example let's take read action, so the content of this xml would be something like this:

   ```
   <Audit
     xmlns="http://www.alfresco.org/repo/audit/model/3.2"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.alfresco.org/repo/audit/model/3.2 alfresco-audit-3.2.xsd"
     >
     <DataExtractors>
       <DataExtractor name="simpleValue" registeredName="auditModel.extractor.simpleValue"/>
     </DataExtractors>

     <DataGenerators>
       <DataGenerator name="personFullName" registeredName="auditModel.generator.personFullName"/>
     </DataGenerators>

     <PathMappings>
       <PathMap source="/alfresco-api/post/ContentService/getReader" target="/node/read"/>
     </PathMappings>

     <Application name="Node" key="node">
       <AuditPath key="read">
         <AuditPath key="no-error">
           <RecordValue key="nodeRef" dataExtractor="simpleValue" dataSource="/node/read/args/nodeRef"/>
           <RecordValue key="propertyQName" dataExtractor="simpleValue" dataSource="/node/read/args/propertyQName"/>
           <RecordValue key="result" dataExtractor="simpleValue" dataSource="/node/read/result"/>
           <GenerateValue key="personFullName" dataGenerator="personFullName"/>
           <GenerateValue key="currentUser" dataGenerator="currentUser"/>
           <GenerateValue key="systemTime" dataGenerator="systemTime"/>
         </AuditPath>
         <AuditPath key="error">
           <RecordValue key="nodeRef" dataExtractor="simpleValue" dataSource="/node/read/args/nodeRef"/>
           <RecordValue key="propertyQName" dataExtractor="simpleValue" dataSource="/node/read/args/propertyQName"/>
           <RecordValue key="error" dataExtractor="simpleValue" dataSource="/node/read/error"/>
           <GenerateValue key="personFullName" dataGenerator="personFullName"/>
           <GenerateValue key="currentUser" dataGenerator="currentUser"/>
           <GenerateValue key="systemTime" dataGenerator="systemTime"/>
         </AuditPath>
       </AuditPath>
     </Application>

   </Audit>
   ```
3. Enable application by calling a webscript, you can check it here: `/alfresco/service/api/audit/control`
4. Now you are able to see the logs here: `/alfresco/service/api/audit/query/Node?verbose=true&limit=10&user=admin`

Comment: Thanks,Is this possible without audit or writing behavior or policies in alfresco?Me and Jaynil have used spring interceptor to track the actions.